# How do I derive the formula S(G,k)=S(G+e,k)+S(G/e,k)?

Tags: combinatorics, stirling-numbers

I found this in a paper from Auburn University and they just state it but do not derive it. I would like to know how to derive it.

I'm fairly certian that e is edges in the graph G, but I don't know where to start by the derivation.

Comment: What is $S(G,k)$?

Comment: Its the stirling number

Comment: Compare to similar [Deletion-contraction formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deletion%E2%80%93contraction_formula) Wikipedia article.

Comment: @mustachetherapy Sure, what is the definition of Stirling number with graphs?